# Sort a GenericList<T> by date property

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, comparison, generic-list

I can't figure out how to do this, these two questions aren't working for me. One says I can't use the delegate and the comparer, and the other says that it can't convert the lambda to a delegate.

[Sort Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116754/sort-generic-list)

[How do I sort a generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177373/how-do-i-sort-a-generic-list)

I have a `GenericList<T>` of `ScheduleItem`. Each item has a `PaymentDate` property which is a `DateTime?`.

I basically want to sort this list on that property (old->newest). What's the easiest way to do this?

First I tried this:

```
transaction.ScheduleCollection.Sort(delegate(ScheduleItem p1, ScheduleItem p2)
                {
                    return p1.PaymentDate.CompareTo(p2.PaymentDate);
                });
```

And I get these two errors:

> Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Collections.IComparer'
>   because it is not a delegate type
>
> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for
>   'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And the other one I tried was this:

```
transaction.ScheduleCollection.Sort((lhs, rhs) => (lhs.PaymentDate.CompareTo(rhs.PaymentDate)));
```

and get

> Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Collections.IComparer'
>   because it is not a delegate type

```
public void Sort(IComparer comparer);
```

That's the sort method I have to work with.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong with perfectly good solutions, when you don't provide any code...

Comment: What is `GenericList<T>`? That's a collection I'm unfamiliar with...

Comment: Have Nikhil or I answered your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you thought about using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)?

Something like: 
`var list = list.OrderBy(x => x.PaymentDate).ToList();`

Comment: It doesn't have `Distinct()` because it's a `GenericList<T>`, not a `List<T>`

Comment: What is GenericList? Something you made up?

Answer (score 3):

Use a LINQ lambda function:

```
var OrderScheduleItem = ScheduleItems.OrderBy(p => p.PaymentDate);
```